# Android and/or Whatsapp degrading photos

Tags: photos

My friend asked me about a problem on her Android phone with Whatsapp.

Phone is Huawei, Y330-U01; Android 4.2.2.
No apps related to Cloud (see comments below) except latest versions of Google Drive and Huawei backup.

People send her pictures and they look fine the first time, but if she tries to open them the second time, they are "blurred" (her words).  She showed me one, and what is happening is that they have been degraded to something like twenty or thirty pixels wide!  Like TV stations do when nudity is on the screen--only far worse, like a whole person three blocks wide!

And videos that play the first time only, the second time cannot play at all.

I suspected some function was degrading them to save storage space, but the internal storage has almost a gigabyte available, and there is an SD card with almost four GB.

She had a lot of updates pending, but neither Whatsapp nor the O.S. were on the list.

What might be the cause and how to fix?

Comment: Device name and model? I'm asking this because there are some devices like Nextbit Robin that backs up photos to cloud and deletes them from the device automatically. Or is there any such cloud app installed?

Comment: Don't know model; four-year-old Huawei.  Don't know about cloud.  I will ask if I see her again.

Comment: Or do you think this maybe the reason? https://lifehacker.com/google-photos-can-now-free-up-space-on-your-phone-1743304827

Comment: No, they are not being deleted nor “degraded to high quality.”  They are being degraded to such a low quality that they can’t be recognized.  Also, the article says “will let you.’  Nothing is “letting‘ her do it, it is doing it without asking her.